# Spurious `.pdf' added to the first argument of \href if inside \ExplSyntaxOn/Off

Tags: hyperref, expl3, links

The following MWE shows that a spurious "`.pdf`" is added to the URL given in the first argument of `\href` if (and only if, AFAICS) the latter is used inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff` (it also shows that there is no trouble with the `\url` command).

Do you see what's going on and how to get rid of this trouble?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\begin{document}

\section{href}

\subsection{Inside ``ExplSyntax'' (NOT okay)}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\href{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}{foo}
~$\rightarrow$~\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo.pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\subsection{Outside ``ExplSyntax'' (okay)}
\href{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}{foo}
~$\rightarrow$~\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}

\section{url}

\subsection{Inside ``ExplSyntax'' (okay)}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\subsection{Outside ``ExplSyntax'' (okay)}
\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The hack provided by egreg answers my question w.r.t. my MWE, but not in my real use case which involves a package, as shown by the following M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mynicepackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mynicepackage}{2016/04/18} {0.1}{mynicepackage}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__npkg_package:nnn
{
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
    {%
      \textsf{#3}
    }{
      \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
      {%
        \href{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/#3}{\textsf{#3}}%
      }{%
        \href{#2}{\textsf{#3}}%
      }%
    }
  }{
    \textsf{#3}%
  }
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\package}{ s O{} m } {
  \__npkg_package:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% Below is the hack provided by egreg:
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \endlinechar=-1 %
  \catcode`\^^A=14 %
  \catcode`\^^M\active
  \catcode`\%\active
  \catcode`\#\active
  \catcode`\_\active
  \catcode`\$\active
  \catcode`\&\active
  \gdef\hyper@normalise{^^A
    \begingroup
    \@makeother{:}^^A THIS WAS MISSING
    \catcode`\^^M\active
    \def^^M{ }^^A
    \catcode`\%\active
    \let%\@percentchar
    \let\%\@percentchar
    \catcode`\#\active
    \def#{\hyper@hash}^^A
    \def\#{\hyper@hash}^^A
    \@makeother\&^^A
    \edef&{\string&}^^A
    \edef\&{\string&}^^A
    \edef\textunderscore{\string_}^^A
    \let\_\textunderscore
    \catcode`\_\active
    \let_\textunderscore
    \let~\hyper@tilde
    \let\~\hyper@tilde
    \let\textasciitilde\hyper@tilde
    \let\\\@backslashchar
    \edef${\string$}^^A
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \hyper@n@rmalise
  }^^A
\endgroup
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mynicepackage}
\begin{document}
\package{foo} $\rightarrow$ \url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that `hyperref` is fooled by the fact that after `\ExplSyntaxOn` the colon has category code 11.

Comment: href tries to detect the link type and as the : has a different catcode it doesn't recognize the http:. You get something similar outside expl3 with `\href{http//www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}{foo}`.  Not quite sure how one get around  it.

Comment: Inserting an url at code level feels wrong. Through separating code level and input level this should resolve itself. (Of course this depends on your actual use case)

Comment: @egreg Okay but why is there no trouble with `\url`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Because `\url` makes no attempt to decide what type of link you're specifying.

Comment: @clemens The MWE is a simplification of some package's code where I define a document command `\pkg` such that `\pkg{foo}` is roughly supposed to expand into `\href{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}{foo}`. How would you separate code level and input level for this?

Comment: In the example you added, the command `\href` (precisely `\hyper@normalise`) cannot do anything with its first argument, because it appears as the argument to another command, so it's already tokenized.

Comment: @egreg And this is hopeless?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé No, of course; but your original question was misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since @egreg already explained what the issue is – here is a suggestion which circumvents the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
 % this saves the url with all characters catcode other:
\str_const:Nn \c__npkg_standard_url_str { http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ }

% separate formatting:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__npkg_package_format:n #1
  { \textsf {#1} }

% the main macro
%   #1: boolean (true => no hyperlink)
%   #2: optional url
%   #3: package name
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__npkg_package:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \texorpdfstring
      {
        \bool_if:nTF {#1}
          { \__npkg_package_format:n {#3} }
          {
            \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
              {
                \href
                  { \c__npkg_standard_url_str #3 }
                  { \__npkg_package_format:n {#3} }
              }
              { \href {#2} { \__npkg_package_format:n {#3} } }
          }
      }
      {#3}
  }

% the user macro:
\NewDocumentCommand {\package} {sO{}m}
  { \__npkg_package:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{\package{acro}}

\package[http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf]{pgf}
\package*{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DenisBitouzé BTW: `\texorpdfstring` doesn't have any effect when `\package` and also  `\__npkg_package:nnn` aren't expandable.

Comment: Just as a comment of style: I think it would be better to have two functions, `:nn` and `:nnn`, rather than have that `\tl_if_blank:nTF`. Then, use `\IfNoValueTF` in the `\NewDocumentCommand` to determine which to use.

Comment: @SeanAllred I very much dislike code duplication which is why I indeed prefer the `\tl_if_blank:nTF` version. (Actually one could avoid code duplication and still have two macros with another layer of abstraction. So this probably a matter of taste… )

Comment: Your parenthetical is exactly what I would do :-) https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/178fcf77764e53fdf3c0cde73779e4c5 You could take it further and abstract the `*` argument into another function (and I think that would be better/purer), but then it just gets a little weird. Especially for a one-off.

Answer (score 5):

The `\hyper@normalise` function applied by `\href` does not take into account that `:` might have a different category code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \endlinechar=-1 %
  \catcode`\^^A=14 %
  \catcode`\^^M\active
  \catcode`\%\active
  \catcode`\#\active
  \catcode`\_\active
  \catcode`\$\active
  \catcode`\&\active
  \gdef\hyper@normalise{^^A
    \begingroup
    \@makeother{:}^^A THIS WAS MISSING
    \catcode`\^^M\active
    \def^^M{ }^^A
    \catcode`\%\active
    \let%\@percentchar
    \let\%\@percentchar
    \catcode`\#\active
    \def#{\hyper@hash}^^A
    \def\#{\hyper@hash}^^A
    \@makeother\&^^A
    \edef&{\string&}^^A
    \edef\&{\string&}^^A
    \edef\textunderscore{\string_}^^A
    \let\_\textunderscore
    \catcode`\_\active
    \let_\textunderscore
    \let~\hyper@tilde
    \let\~\hyper@tilde
    \let\textasciitilde\hyper@tilde
    \let\\\@backslashchar
    \edef${\string$}^^A
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \hyper@n@rmalise
  }^^A
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\section{href}

\subsection{Inside ``ExplSyntax'' (NOT okay)}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\href{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}{foo}
~$\rightarrow$~\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo.pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\subsection{Outside ``ExplSyntax'' (okay)}
\href{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}{foo}
~$\rightarrow$~\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}

\section{url}

\subsection{Inside ``ExplSyntax'' (okay)}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\subsection{Outside ``ExplSyntax'' (okay)}
\url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo}
\end{document}
```

You can check that the link is as expected.

---

The example you added after my answer is *very* different from the one in the original question. You're calling `\href` in the argument to another command and so the argument to `\href` would be already tokenized and not be influenced by `\hyper@normalise`.

You can use `\tl_rescan:nn` in order to force rereading of the argument.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mynicepackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mynicepackage}{2016/04/18} {0.1}{mynicepackage}

\NewDocumentCommand{\package}{ s o m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \textsf{#3}
   }
   {
    \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
     {
      \__npkg_package:nn { http://www.ctan.org/pkg/#3 } { #3 }
     }
     {
      \__npkg_package:nn { #2 } { #3 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__npkg_package:nn
 {
  \texorpdfstring { \tl_rescan:nn { } { \href{#1}{\textsf{#2}} } } { #2 }
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mynicepackage}

\begin{document}

\package{foo} $\rightarrow$ \url{http://www.ctan.org/pkg/foo.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Note the different definition of the `\package` command, according to the guidelines.

If a URL contains a `%` you're doomed, of course, unless you escape it.

[image]

Comment: Should I report this to Heiko?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I think you should

Comment: Trouble reported.

Comment: Unfortunately, your hack doesn't work if included in a package. See my updated question.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Neither it would work if you had `%` in the URL

Comment: Sorry for this example added after your answer being very different from the one in the original question: I wasn't aware of this. Now, I don't know which answer I should accept :(

Comment: About the different definition of the `\package` command, according to the guidelines, I also have a document command `\Package` which is similar to `\package`: it adds "package" word before or after depending on the current language (English or French). With the way you follow, `\Package` definition would need to duplicate all the "logic" (star or not, optional argument or not) whereas, with my way, I can reuse the logic within `\__npkg_package`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Checking of arguments should belong to `\NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: Why checking of arguments should belong to `\NewDocumentCommand`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Because that's the reason `xparse` is that way; ask Frank. ;-)

Comment: Today's upgrade of TeX Live/pretest shows that `hyperref` has been amended to also have `\@makeother\:` in `\hyper@normalise`; it will be in TeX Live 2016.